# Java code "NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();"

Tags: java, reference, abstract-class, new-operator, number-formatting

What is the difference between the followings

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
```

and

```
NumberFormat nf = new NumberFormat()
```

Why we need to declare NumberFormat object as the first one?

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `new NumberFormat()`; as the very first line of the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) notes,

> `NumberFormat` is the abstract base class for all number formats.

You can't directly instantiate an abstract class, so a [creational pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern) is used.